# Смена цвета кнопки в Android

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

Не могу понять как сменить цвет кнопки, по умолчанию кнопка залилась фиолетовым; смена background не помогла мне

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buyBtn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="133dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="КУПИТЬ"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

[image: Фиолетовая кнопочка]

Comment: Xml код добавьте

Comment: @ArtyMorris done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

замените

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

на

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

> background не меняет цвет кнопок, а backgroundTint меняет, точно не
> знаю в чем дело, но когда трогаешь первое то у тебя пропадают все
> настройки по типу радиуса или инсета, наверное это из за того что
> button имеет свою чуть более подточенную модель макета, в любом случае
> это должно решить вашу проблема, а для большей кастомизации рекомендую
> использовать shape как уже описали тут

Answer (score 2):

Ну тут идете в папочку res/drawable создаете там файлик разметки. Условно назовем его :

```
button.xml
```

Описываете внешний вид вашей кнопки. Цвет, Закругление углов и прочее. Как пример:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/holo_red_dark"
    />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
```

Ну и потом при создании кнопки в вашем layout указываете данный xml файл в качестве background :

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/buyBtn"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
android:layout_width="133dp"
android:layout_height="54dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:text="КУПИТЬ"
android:background="@drawable/button"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Ну еще, конечно, стиль лучше написать для всех подобных кнопок с повторяющимся дизайном. Но это уже совсем другая история...

Comment: Так, это конечно хорошо, но почему у меня дефолтная кнопка не меняет цвет с фиолетового вообще никак?

Comment: @Slavatar вот эту строчку уберите  - style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"