# Не изменяется цвет кнопки

Tags: android

Почему не меняется цвет кнопки после такой строчки в xml-коде

```
android:background="@color/black"
```

Цвет кнопки установился изначально фиолетовый, и не меняется больше.

Comment: Приведите весь код xml кнопки

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246525/Смена-цвета-кнопки-в-android/1247919#comment2191261_1246546 ?

Comment: @pavlofff что-то много проблем с фиолетовыми кнопками в последнее время)